Knowing all spin components at the same time
You can't know all spin components simultaneously due to the commutation relation (& Heisenberg's uncertainty principle):
$[S_x, S_y] = i\hbar S_z$
But what if you know that $S_z=0$? Then that implies that $S_x$ and $S_y$ commute and thus you know all components at the same time.
Note: that $S^2$ doesn't have to be equal to 0, since $S_x$ and $S_y$ can be non-zero. This is what I want to stress, as opposed to the answer is another linked post in the comments, which assumes that $s=0$.
Note: I am referring to the eigenvalues of the operators. So with $S_z = 0$ I mean that $m_s = 0$, i.e. an eigenstate of $S_z$ with an eigenvalue of 0.
Edit:
I believe that the conclusion is that the only simultaneous eigenstate of Sx, Sy and Sz are if the eigenvalue is 0. Is this correct?

The operator is not the same as the value. The commutation relations hold for any value.

But if two operators commute that implies that they have simultaneous eigenstates, which means that you have an eigenstate where the eigenvalues corresponding to  $S_x, S_y, S_z$ are all known.

If there is a common eigenstate of Sx, Sy and Sz, doesn't that imply that all of their eigenvalues are defined simultaneously? (since you know that Sz = 0 and then Sx and Sy commute)

I don't understand from that post specifically why l = 0 is necessary. Why can't you have a state | 2 0> for example with l=2 and m=0? This state has Lz = 0, but a nonzero L^2, while at the same time having defined value for Lx and Ly which should have non zero eigenvalues

Your question is a duplicate. If you have doubts, consider to leave a comment under the answer. I honestly don't understand what you mean, sorry.

The logic is that the commutation relations imply that if you have an eigenvector of both $L_x,L_y$, then it must be an eigenvector of $L_z$ with eigenvalue $0$. Using the other commutation relations, obtained by cyclic interchanging the operators, shows that the eigenvalues of $L_x,L_y$ must be $0$, too. Then it is trivial to see that the eigenvalue of $L^2$ is also $0$. This is what the answer is elaborating. Where is the problem with the argument?

Why use spin, when you can work it for orbital angular momentum. The analog to a vector boson is the $P$ state, with eigenfunctions:
$$ |1, m\rangle = Y_1^m(\Omega) $$
with the $m=0$ state looking like:
$$ Y_1^0 \propto \cos\theta = z/r $$
For simplicity, I'll work on the unit sphere:
$$ |1, 0\rangle \propto z $$
It's an eigenstate of:
$$ L_z = x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y\frac{\partial}{\partial x }$$
since $z$ doesn't depend on $x$ or $y$.
If I apply:
$$L_x = y\frac{\partial}{\partial z} - z\frac{\partial}{\partial y }$$
I get:
$$L_x z = y $$
and likewise for $L_x$.
So it is clearly not an eigenstate of $L_x$ or $L_y$.

Is the conclusion that the only simultaneous eigenstate of the three operators are if all of their eigenvalues are 0?
